# Is the answer given to Calculus 9e by Larson section 9.5 question 37.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The problem

> Approximate the sum of the series by using the first six terms.
>
> question #37)    $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n 2}{n!}$

The answer given by [CalcChat](http://www.calcchat.com/book/Calculus-9e/)*: $S_6 = \sum \limits_{n=0}^5 \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n 2}{n!} \approx 0.7333$

$|R_6| = |S-S_6| \leq a_7 = \frac{2}{6!} = 0.002778$

## This is where I have a issue.  $a_7 = \frac{2}{7!}$

Is this poorly worded? I know that $\frac{2}{6!}=a_6$
The solution guide list the interval as $0.7305 \leq S \leq 0.7361$

*Reading the book again and other websites* I think this solution is in correct.

The lower bound should be $S_6-a_7$ and the upper bound should be $S_6+a_7$
$0.7256 \leq S \leq 0.7264$

So am I or the solution guide correct?

- Select 9th edition

Comment: The difficulty seems to be just a matter of notation.  Apparently, $a_7$ is being used to mean the seventh term of the series, which is $\frac2{6!}$ because the series begins with $n=0$, not with $n=1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Now I get it, I must keep a close eye on how the series is index.